# Prevent Python For Loop from overwriting dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, gis, overwrite

I am trying to create a new dictionary (`intersections`) that contains intersecting areas from the polygons in a dictionary called `zones`.

I use `combinations` to find all possible unique combinations of `zones`. Then I use Shapely's `.intersects()` to test `if` the zones intersect. If they do so, I would like their geometry being saved in variable `int_geometry` and then be stored in a dictionary (using: Shapely's `.intersection()`).

I know there are **four** intersections, because this code returns them:

```
for a, b in combinations(zones.values(), 2):
  a_geom = a['location']
  b_geom = b['location']
  if a_geom.intersects(b_geom) == True:
    print a_geom.intersection(b_geom)
```

However, if I replace what comes after the `if` statement like in the code below, it starts overwriting itself.

```
intersections = {}    

for a, b in combinations(zones.values(), 2):
  a_geom = a['location']  
  b_geom = b['location']  
  if a_geom.intersects(b_geom) == True:
    int_geometry = a_geom.intersection(b_geom)
    int_area = round(int_geometry.area,2)
    int_perimeter = round(int_geometry.length,2)
    intersections = {
      'geometry' : int_geometry,
      'attributes' : {
        'area' : int_area,
        'perimeter' : int_perimeter,
      }
    }    

pprint(intersections)
```

There are multiple topics on similar issues, though I cannot find my answer. I know I am overlooking something very obvious here, but I can't detect it. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are reassigning the name `intersections` in each iteration of the `for` loop to a new dictionary. (The one you build on the right hand side.) It's hard to say more because your code is not self contained (we can't copy paste and run it) and the final desired outcome is unclear.

Comment: You probably want something like 
<code>
`intersections[geometry] = {
      'geometry' : int_geometry,
      'attributes' : {
        'area' : int_area,
        'perimeter' : int_perimeter,
      }
    }    
`
</code>
instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` in `int_index = "int_index " + str(index + 1)` will always be the same value as after first loop it's value is constant. Hence data is being overwritten.

```
...

# PART 2 - ANALYSE THE DATA
intersections = {}
index = 0

for a, b in combinations(zones.values(), 2):
  a_geom = a['location']
  b_geom = b['location']
  if a_geom.intersects(b_geom) == True:
    int_index = "int_index " + str(index + 1)
    int_geometry = a_geom.intersection(b_geom)
    int_area = round((a_geom.intersection(b_geom).area),2)
    int_perimeter = round((a_geom.intersection(b_geom).length),2)
    intersections[int_index] = {
      'geometry' : int_geometry,
      'attributes' : {
        'area' : int_area,
        'perimeter' : int_perimeter,
      }
    }
    index += 1

pprint(intersections)
```

Comment: Yes, I would like to store the data, like in your first example and I know how to store the data in a list, but I would like to store it in a dictionary. I just added my full code above. As you can see I (think I) use exactly the same structure for creating the `zones` dictionary. And that works perfectly fine.

Comment: `index` in `int_index = "int_index " + str(index + 1)` will always be the same value as after first loop it's value is constant. Hence overwriting.